# Map looks overcrowded when restaurants are close to each other

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-places-api, apple-maps

I am working on building an app with a map function. We have parsed restaurants from Google Places and put them on Apple Maps for iOS and Google Maps for Android.

Our main problem is that the map looks very crowded when restaurants happen to be close to each other. See example here: http://picpaste.com/MAP_EXAMPLE-P17m5Aqe.png

We can't figure out a good solution for this. Google/Apple seem to have solved it by showing different restaurants depending on the level of zoom. Is there an easy way to replicate the algorithm?

Update: We have tried clustering but it does not really solve the issue when you zoom in enough (as picture above shows).

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use clustering here. There is already an official utility implementation of maps marker clustering [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! We have tried clustering but it does not really solve the issue when you zoom in enough (as picture above shows).

The problem is not when you are zoomed-out because then we have simply decided not to show the red dots at all (similar solution as e.g. Google).

It is the zoomed-in view that is the problem

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make your shared file public??

Comment: Is that in maximum zoom level?? If not then you can apply a cluster in those fuzzy areas. Or you can apply distance based clustering too.

BTW, in this documentation you can find some ways to handle markers. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?hl=en